# Vue Resource empty data

Tags: php, vue.js

I'm trying to make an AJAX call in Vue to a PHP script, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Vue:

```
methods: {
  onSubmit () {
    if (this.valid) {
      this.$http.post('http://remindwordserver.loc/register.php', {test: 'test'}).then(response => {
        console.log(response.body)
      }, response => {})
    }
  }
},
```

PHP:

```
`<?php

print_r($_POST);`
```

`$_POST` is empty

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with PHP, but I'll give it a go.

The `$_POST` variable only contains data from the request when the HTML Content-Type of the request is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`. vue-resource by default sets the Content-Type of the request to `application/json`.

If you want to access JSON data in your PHP script, you'll have to decode the request data from JSON. See [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php).